# Input/output error when writing to google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I created a gcs bucket on https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/
and successfully mounted on an instance with gcsfuse,
however, when I try to write to the mounted directory,  it shows an Input/output error.

```
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000003        connection.go:395] <- LookUpInode (parent 1, name "test")
gcs: Req              0x1: <- StatObject("test/")
gcs: Req              0x2: <- StatObject("test")
gcs: Req              0x1: -> StatObject("test/") (31.355698ms): gcs.NotFoundError: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound
gcs: Req              0x2: -> StatObject("test") (51.589538ms): gcs.NotFoundError: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000003        connection.go:476] -> Error: "no such file or directory"
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000004        connection.go:395] <- MkDir (parent 1, name "test")
gcs: Req              0x3: <- CreateObject("test/")
gcs: Req              0x3: -> CreateObject("test/") (13.513239ms): googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000004        connection.go:476] -> Error: "CreateChildDir: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions"
fuse: 2016/06/09 02:12:40.128885 *fuseops.MkDirOp error: CreateChildDir: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the `--foreground --debug_fuse` output that you're using credentials that aren't allowed to write to the bucket. They are probably read-only (`StatObject` didn't return a 403, and gcsfuse checks at startup that it can list the bucket).

Try giving the [docs about credentials](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#credentials) a careful read. In particular, if you're getting credentials automatically on a Google Compute Engine VM, you probably forgot to create it with the `storage-full` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Please run gcsfuse with `--foreground` (and perhaps `--debug_fuse`) to get some indication of what the error is when it happens.

Comment: I used these two options,  there was no error on output of gcsfuse,  Input/output error only happens when I wrote to the new mounted directory

Comment: Are you sure? `--debug_fuse` shows the response to each request from the kernel, and should indicate what operation failed along with an error message. (You should see all the successful operations too.)

Comment: I attached all command lines,  there were no other error messages.

Comment: You forgot `--foreground`. Without that, stderr goes to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Yes, you are right !  with --foreground,  when trying to make a directory 'test' I can see there are two errors,  404 and 403,  but I don't know how to solve